# How to animate a rotated DOM element with CSS

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

Full code is on: https://jsfiddle.net/k1t7gy8L/

I have the following HTML:

```
<section class="cd-intro">
  <div class="cd-intro-content mask-2">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="inner">
        <h1>Animated Intro Section</h1>
        <p>A collection of text effects for the intro section of your website</p>
        <div class="action-wrapper">
          <a href="#0" class="cd-btn main-action">Get started</a>
          <a href="#0" class="cd-btn">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.mask-2.cd-intro-content .content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #0F0;
}
.mask-2.cd-intro-content .content-wrapper .inner{
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    background-color: #F00;
}
.mask-2.cd-intro-content .content-wrapper > div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.mask-2.cd-intro-content .content-wrapper,
.mask-2.cd-intro-content .content-wrapper > div {
  animation-duration: 3.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.1s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

.mask-2.cd-intro-content .content-wrapper {
  animation-name: cd-mask-wrapper;
}

.mask-2.cd-intro-content .content-wrapper > div {
  animation-name: cd-mask-content;
}
@keyframes cd-mask-wrapper {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes cd-mask-content {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

Everything works like a charm: Except that the rotation on `transform:rotate(45deg);` only takes effect AFTER the animation. Why is that? How can I rotate it prior to the animation?.

My idea idea is to reveal the content with a diagonal line instead of a vertical line.

Comment: try to remove your css `transform:rotate(-45deg);` in `.mask-2.cd-intro-content .content-wrapper .inner`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare everything on transform. But also you have to note that translate will be rotated, so with the superpower of geometry you can do this:

```
@keyframes cd-mask-wrapper {
0% {
-webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translateX(50%) rotate(45deg);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: translateX(0)  rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
transform: translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
}
}
@keyframes cd-mask-content {
0% {
-webkit-transform:  rotate(-45deg) translateX(-100%);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-100%);
-ms-transform:  rotate(-45deg) translateX(-100%);
-o-transform:  rotate(-45deg) translateX(-100%);
transform:  rotate(-45deg) translateX(-100%);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(0);
-moz-transform rotate(-45deg) translateX(0);
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(0);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(0);
transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(0);
}
}
```

Yes. IT is  important to translate then rotate the wrapper. And rotate and then translate the content. Test it =)